# Difference between IFNULL and IF

Tags: mysql

Is there a difference between the following two statements:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT IF(arms IS NULL, 'asdf', arms) FROM limbs;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | limbs | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |   12 |       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT IF(arms IS NULL, 'asdf', arms) FROM limbs;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | limbs | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |   12 |       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Does one perform better or is preferable over the other? Or are they identical?

Comment: Your two statements are _literally_ the same. There is no difference between them.

Comment: `EXPLAIN` doesn't depend on the `SELECT` (until you don't have nested queries there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IFNULL` is just a [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for `IF`, which is a syntactic sugar for ANSI SQL `CASE`.

So use whichever you like better and whichever fits your particular needs.

PS: `EXPLAIN` doesn't rely on `SELECT`